# Select query only returns string up until blank space

Tags: php, sql

Here is my select query:

```
$username = $_GET['username'];
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare('SELECT email, phone, addressLine1, addressLine2, city, postcode            FROM users WHERE username = ?');
$stmt->bind_param('s', $username);

$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($email, $phone, $addressLine1, $addressLine2, $city, $postcode);
$stmt->fetch();
printf('<p>Address Line 1:</p> <input type="text" name="AddressLine1" value=%s><br>', $addressLine1);
```

However, instead of $addressLine1 giving the result "A test address" it will only give "A"

I have been at this for a while but haven't worked it out yet.

They are stored as `VARCHAR`s in my DB.

EDIT:
This is where i use addressLine1

```
printf('<p>Address Line 1:</p> <input type="text" name="AddressLine1" value=%s><br>', $addressLine1);
```

Comment: Show where/how you use `$addressLine1`

Comment: printf('<p>Address Line 1:</p> <input type="text" name="AddressLine1" value=%s><br>', $addressLine1);

Comment: @Waq please edit your answer to post that code, rather than including it in an unformatted comment.

Comment: Ah okay, will do. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a space in your text and if you use that as an html attribute make sure and quote it else the attribute terminates at the first space

```
printf('<p>Address Line 1:</p> <input type="text" name="AddressLine1" value="%s"><br>', $addressLine1);
```

Comment: Yup, that fixed it. I was looking in the wrong place. Thanks a lot for that. Sorry asking the wrong question!

Answer (score 0):

It is either your database doesn't have what you think or you are not seeing your variable properly

You should try seeing the length of address line 1 and make sure it is 1